# Replay a youtube video when clicking on an element

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I have a div element which is a link and I want it to be able to play a video once again.
My jQuery code is this :

```
$('#film').click(
function() {
    $('#question').hide();
    $('#video').show();
});
```

I know that the YouTube javascript API has a `player.playVideo()`function but I can't figure out how to implement it inside my jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

I found out with the help of [Hidden youtube player loses its methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197868/hidden-youtube-player-loses-its-methods) that it was because I was hiding and showing back the player.
I changed it to `$('#video').css('visibility','hidden');` for hiding and `$('#video').css('visibility','visible');` for showing it back and it works. My final code is :

```
function play() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.playVideo();
  }
}

$('#film').click(
function() {
    $('#question').hide();
    $('#video').css('visibility','visible');
    play();
});
```